# C++ problems with array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object

We have an assignment to create a game of blackjack.

Bellow is simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Deck
{
private:
    Card cards[52];    <-- HERE!!
public:

};

class Card
{
private:
    int suit;
    int number;
public:


    int getSuit();
    int getNumber();
    void setCard(int suit, int number);

};
int Card::getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}

int Card::getNumber()
{
    return number;
}

void Card::setCard(int s, int n)
{
    suit = s;
    number = n;
}

class Players
{
private:
    Card PlayersCards[10];
public: 
    /*Card getCard();*/


};

//Card Players::getCard()
//{
//  return;
//}

int main()
{
    Players user;


    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is where the array of objects Card is being created. the compiler gives me the following errors:

> Error C3646   'cards': unknown override specifier
>
> Error C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '['
>
> Error C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
>
> Error C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't understand the class Card, it throws the parser, making the error messages quite obtuse.

Comment: I feel for you. The fact that C++ requires forward declarations at all (unlike other languages, cf C#, that do the work for you) plus the fact that the error message is misleading ... sigh. Why do we program in C++ again? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what Card is, so cannot generate the right code.

The class `Card` needs to be declared before the class `Deck`, as `Card` is included in the `Deck`.

```
class Card {
    /// stuff - allows compiler to work out the size of one Card.
};

class Deck {
  private:
    Card cards[52];    // knows how to create 52 of these.
};
// implementation can go later.
int Card::getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}
```

Comment: oh what a stupid mistake -.- no wonder I couldnt think of anything wrong with the code cause it was because of ordering ! anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: @user5714811 Please mark the answer as accepted and upvote it if it has helped you to solve your problem.